# implementation tensorflow with react native CLi for Object Detection

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to implementation tensorflow with React Native But I didn't get any lead. I want to do Object Detection. if SomeOne knows then please let me know. it will help me alot.